# How to handle a javax.persistence.NoResult Exception when there are no entries in database?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database query and check by the email address if there is a user with this email address.
I´m using Hibernate ORM.

This works so far. But if there are no users in the database, I get the following error:

> javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query

Query code:

```
public UserEntity findUserEntityByEmail(String email) {
    UserEntity userEntity = null;
    try {
        startOperation(false);
        userEntity = getSession().createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE u.email IN :email", UserEntity.class)
                .setParameter("email", email)
                .getSingleResult();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        getSession().close();
    }
    return userEntity;
}
```

I also understand the error message. But how can I work around this case, when there are no entries in the Database?

Does anyone know about this case?

Comment: We should catch the `NoResultException` and act accordingly. To say what "accordingly" means, we would need to have a deeper understanding wrt. the business logic.

Comment: With `getSingleResult()` you are basically saying that there will be exactly one result. The query you are running does not convey that. It could have 0, 1, or many resulting records. Use `getResultList()` instead, and then examine this resulting list.

Comment: Yeah, nice. This resolved it. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can bypass the error.

```
public UserEntity findUserEntityByEmail(String email) {
    List<UserEntity> userEntityList = null;
    try {
        startOperation(false);
        userEntityList = getSession().createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE u.email IN :email", UserEntity.class)
                .setParameter("email", email)
                .getResultList();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        getSession().close();
    }
    return (userEntityList != null && userEntityList.size() > 0) ? userEntityList.get(0) : null;
}
```